# What action plan a hacker can do to enter an iPhone

Tags: mobile, iphone, sms

I am interested by mobile protection for general public, we have all information saved on our phone. I am thinking what action plan a hacker can do with Kali or other to enter an iPhone and read SMS, for example. I found several methods but I don't think there is a method which works:

- The first is to steal an iCloud backup stored on a computer and brute force the password. After that, the hacker can read all data stored in the backup.
- There is also an exploit [iOS MobileSafari LibTIFF Buffer Overflow](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/21868/) but it had been patched there is a long time ago...
- The last solution I think is to hook web browser with BeeF. I don't know very well BeeF so I don't know what is it possible to do when Safari for iOS is hooked.

Comment: It seems like you are asking us to hack an IPhone to read someones SMSes. I must warn you that attempting this on someone else' device is illegal in most countries. Even if this is your girlfriend or parent.

Comment: Kali has nothing to do with this. To get data out of any iPhone after the 5 requires physical access and the pincode to unlock it. But at that point you can also just read the info on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not against explaining Hijacking techniques for educational purpose. But please, keep in mind that gaining access to device that you do not own without it's owner permission is **strictly illegal**

That being said, gaining a remote access to an up to date IOS device (**without any physical access to it**) is a hard task, even for an infosec guy. It's not something you can achieve by watching some Youtube videos explaining how to use Kali tools.

(Beside this, asking tips on accessing apple device 100% remotely on a public forum is bad.)

But since you're supposed to do this for shaping your information security knowledge, i will assume you own an iOS device and have a **physical** access to it. 
The procedure include 4 steps, you will need to perform your own research, from my point of view it's the best way to learn.

So here we go.

**1. Fetching the PIN.** 
Black boxes and the goliath tool might help.

**2. Maintaining the access (Remotly).**
You want to access the device from anywhere. Installing a VNC server on your iOS device will be the easiest way, Netcat should be ok as well.

**3. Remain Stealthy**
Here comes the hard part: not getting caught nor raising alert. Stealthy pushing & installing a handcrafted app that hide your presence would be my way of doing it.

**4. Being contagious**
Very hard but possible: Stealthy delete the iCloud backup and replace them with the corrupted version you just crafted with the 3 steps above. It should give you access to new iOS devices, if the OS is installed from the corrupted backup (your handcrafted app have a big role in this point).